# Creating Managed Metadata field in html sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-2013, taxonomy, managed, jsgrid

I am showing sharepoint list in jsgrid in custom html.
One of the column in list is of managed metadata type. I want to show this field in jsgrid along with editing. Possible?

Comment: Not sure you question has enough details. How does "custom html" look like and how do you provide it? What do you mean by "managed metadata type"?

Comment: @tabalin I have a site page on which in content editor webpart I have linked html page. where I am showing an input field which I want to render as a taxonomy field in SharePoint 2013. Can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you want to render a managed metadata field in your own jsgrid.
I believe this tutorial could be a start for you

https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP/tree/master/Components/Core.TaxonomyPicker